# How Can solve problems with laravel queues using redis?

Tags: laravel, redis

I use redis to manage the processing Laravel Queues, but in some moments the queue simply stops running. I put the queue command on the supervisor but sometimes I have to restart the supervisor to get back up and running. What can it be?

Update 1 - supervisor config:

```
[program:m-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/m-cms/artisan queue:work --timeout=600 --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/m-cms/storage/logs/worker.log
~
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have to configure supervisor to restart the queue worker if it stops, and you have to configure your system to keep supervisor running. Have you done both of those things? Update your question with the things you have tried.

Comment: @newUserName02 I have already configured supervisor... I updated the question with the supervisor config